# htaccess causing index.php to download

Tags: php, .htaccess, virtualhost, zend-server-ce

I am working on a site that depends on the following htaccess file to create something of a virtual directory structure by redirecting to an index.php whenever the specified url doesn't exist on the system.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That seems to work fine on the client's existing server. It invisibly redirects things like domain.com/checkout to domain.com/index.php?p=checkout

My problem is that on my local development environment, this causes any non-existing url like that domain.com/checkout, or even the root domain.com to DOWNLOAD the index.php

If I try to load a specific file that exists in the website such as domain.com/index.php then it parses and displays in the browser properly.

In case it matters, my development environment is configured with a Virtual Host on Zend Server Community Edition.

Comment: Try removing the `AddHandler` rule. It's quite useless anyway, and probably incorrect for your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you've already configured PHP in your development server for all files with the `*.php` extension. That means that doing it again in your `.htaccess` files is not only unnecessary but it can possibly cancel your server's configuration (as it's actually doing). Thus you need to get rid of this line:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

The question is why it's there in the first place. I'd expect any PHP-enabled hosting service to be configured by default :-?